# What's the Perl equivalent of Ruby "foo".hash?

Tags: ruby, perl, hashcode

The [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000766) method on a Ruby String returns a number based on the string's length and content:

```
>> "foo".hash
=> 876516207
```

What's the equivalent in Perl?

Comment: I'm curious how Ruby people use that. What good is a Ruby specific hash value outside of Ruby?

Comment: Ruby, IIRC, is like Java. All the objects are in a hash table and so it's basically the ID of the item.

Comment: Yeah, but what are you going to do with the ID of an object? :)

Comment: @brian: The hash method in ruby and the getHashCode method in java are used by hash-based datastructures like hash maps. They have nothing to do with an object's id, except that for class Object the hashcode is defined to be the object's id (but not for strings. Two strings have the same hash code when they have the same content, not the same memory location).

Comment: @briandfoy: one can use the hash code to _sample_ the data stream in a predictable way (e.g., take only objects with hash code divisible by 100 for a 1% sample).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get a digest of an arbitrary string, check out the [Digest](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Digest/Digest.pm) module on CPAN, which supports MD5 and SHA1/2. You can truncate the result for however many characters you need.

Comment: No need to hit CPAN.  `Digest` and `Digest::MD5` are core in Perl 5.8, `Digest::SHA` is also core as of Perl 5.10.

Comment: This seems to be an overkill for small strings.

Answer (score 3):

You could also take a look at the Ruby source code to see how the hash is generated for String objects in case you want to write something similar in Perl. The resulting hash is a function of the string length and contents and is calculated in [rb_str_hash()](http://ruby-doc.org/doxygen/1.8.4/string_8c-source.html#l00852).

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity, what are you going to use the hash for? The Digest module is probably good enough for most purposes, but there are some cases when you might want to roll your own. Rare, but possible.

Comment: I have a stream of objects with string IDs which I want to sample in a predictable way (i.e., I cannot use random because when I see a dupe I must know whether it is sampled or not). Digest seems like an overkill; I don't need 128 bits; 16 bits is more then enough for me. I am also afraid that Digest will kill me performance-wise.